# How can I create separate Rails applications that shares same models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got web application and api.

- Web application is traditional application that renders views.
- Api is stateless REST services.

Web application and api will run on separate servers.

How can I share model classes between them?

Comment: Take a look at this : http://www.agileadvisor.com/2008/01/using-activerecord-outside-rails.html it's not much but it would allow to at least use all the data in a simple manner. I am also looking for a solution to this problem but I can't find one that I like. Another one I found http://blog.aizatto.com/2007/05/21/activerecord-without-rails/

Answer (score 2):

You could write a gem with the models you want to share. Then use the gem in both applications.

Another way would be to use the same application on both servers where the application and the api are both implemented. Then one could disable the app/api depend on the domain.